# R: character "1:10" convert numeric 1:10?

Tags: r

Recent, I use the following code.

```
answer <- readline("please input the number.")
```

Then I input 1:10, then press Enter.
Here answer = "1:10", if there is a method to convert the character "1:10" to numeric 1:10?

Comment: Ugly, but `eval(parse(text = answer))`?

Comment: Why ugly?  That's pretty much what the command line interpreted does, right?

Comment: @BrodieG Ugly because the user is a prick and enters `unlink(every_file_everywhere)`.

Comment: @KonradRudolph at which point they delete every file on their own computer?  From the context it seems like the code has to be running on the person inputting the number's computer.

Comment: @KonradRudolph. "Ugly because the user is a prick and enters unlink(every_file_everywhere)."  what does this sentence mean?

Comment: @Kevin, BrodieG explained it already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try

```
x = '1:10'
inp = as.integer(strsplit(x, ':')[[1]])
inp[1]:inp[2]
[1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
```

It's ugly, but it works with no collateral damage.

Comment: @kevin, this is quite different from `1:10`.

Comment: @AnandaMahto True but it's easy enough to make the sequence and avoids the pitfall Konrad brings up as you'd just get an error.  Some error handling/checking could be useful here to avoid malicious activity.

Answer (score 2):

My comment as an answer: look at `eval(parse(text = ...))`.

The basic idea would be to put it in a function like:

```
fun <- function() {
  answer <- readline("Please input the number: ")
  eval(parse(text = answer))
}
fun()
```

Generally, however, one tries to avoid `eval(parse(text = ...))` type things in R.

---

```
library(fortunes)
fortune(106)
```

Comment: Thanks all. I learn a lot from you, which encourage me learning R more and more.